# Eclipse Oxygen fails to install on RPi

Tags: pi-3

**Question:**

HOW do I install and run Eclipse Oxygen for Linux 32 on Raspberry Pi?

**Problem / Setup Description:**

I am unable to run an application Eclipse which runs just fine on Unbutu 32 bit OS.

My process follows these steps:

1. On Ubuntu 32 bit OS I access vendor’s site and “download” Eclipse Oxygen 
   package for Linux 32 bits.
2. Setup folder “Oxygen_32”, in dedicated partition on my HDD.
3. Setup folder “Eclipse_Oxygen” as subfolder in folder “Oxygen_32”
4. Copy downloaded file from Ubuntu “Download “ folder to “Eclipse_Oxygen” folder.
5. Extract downloaded file to “Eclipse_Oxygen”.
6. Right click on “eclipse” file in “Eclipse_Oxygen”.
7. Get pop-up menu whose first option is “Run”.
8. Selecting “Run” will activate Eclipse Oxygen software and I can build and run simple C++ “Hello world” application.
9. On Raspberry 32 bit OS I access vendors site and “download” Eclipse Oxygen 
   package for Linux 32 bits.
10. Setup folder “Oxygen_32”, in dedicated partition on my working USB drive.
11. Setup folder “Eclipse_Oxygen” as subfolder in folder “Oxygen_32”
12. Copy downloaded file  from Ubuntu “Download “ folder to “Eclipse_Oxygen” folder.
13. Extract downloaded file to “Eclipse_Oxygen”.
14. Right click on “eclipse” file in “Eclipse_Oxygen” and get a pop-up menu whose first option is “Open” and the second option is “Eclipse”. Selecting “Open” will bring up a dialog indicating that I am attempting to run an executable file and give me an option to do that.
15. After selecting `yes, execute...`, there is no feedback from the OS and NOTHING indicating that the Eclipse app is being activated.
16. Selecting “Eclipse” activates “Eclipse 3.8” and NOT the Eclipse Oxygen version I am after.

**PS**

The command line `apt-get install eclipse` or `apt-get install eclipse-cdt` will ALWAYS install `Eclipse 3.8`.

Comment: This is a site for professionals, not Reddit. There's no reason for the aggressive paragraph towards the end. That said, until a package maintainer updates the Eclipse package, it will remain at 3.8. How long have you waited for eclipse to start? Eclipse is notoriously slow on the RPi, so you may have not been patient enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eclipse binary file you downloaded is for an `x86` architecture. As such, it is totally incompatible with the RPi's `ARM` processor. If you want to run the latest version of Eclipse, you'll need to download the source code and compile it yourself.

Comment: It is a same source - Linux 32 bits dowload which is working on Ubuntu OS ARM hardware , not x86.

Comment: @JanHus: I don't see any downloads on the Eclipse website that lists support for ARM hardware. Where exactly did you find it?

Comment: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU J1900 @ 1.99GHz × 4  VERY SORRY , edit alligator got me. You are  the man!

Comment: @JanHus: You realize that a Celeron processor is an `x86` architecture, correct?

Comment: Yep, sometime hitting me over the head would work better! My wife  is very successful doing that !

Comment: If ever you're not sure what arch a binary is for, you can use `file` on it.  `file` says that `eclipse-inst` is for `Intel 80386`, which is the 32-bit x86.